# TreeView_SetExtendedStyle does not apply certain styles, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, treeview

I wanted to "play around" with [new extended styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759981(v=vs.85).aspx), especially the ones that manipulate with checkboxes.

The problem is that none of them seem to work.

*I can not determine if `TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` works or not, because my treeview is small. I haven't tested `TVS_EX_RICHTOOLTIP` yet. Apart from that, no matter what other style I set, I am unable to see any effect.*

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
HWND hwndTV = CreateWindowEx(...);
// first, add checkboxes
DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwndTV, GWL_STYLE);
dwStyle |= TVS_CHECKBOXES;
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndTV, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
// now add extended window styles
HRESULT h = TreeView_SetExtendedStyle(hwndTV, 
    TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES, TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES);
// insert items...
```

I have checked the return value of the [TreeView_SetExtendedStyle macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760053(v=vs.85).aspx) and it did not fail, which increases my frustration even more.

### QUESTION:

Can you show me how to properly apply extended styles? For example, how to properly set `TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES` or any other?

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting `TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES` *before* you turn on `TVS_CHECKBOXES` (just guessing, but it wouldn't surprise me if it needs to be set at the time the state imagelist is created).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Jesus Christ!!! It worked. I can't believe documentation omitted this very important fact! Thank you so much. If you post this as an answer I will accept and upvote -> you really should for the sake of future readers...

Comment: Well that was a good guess :)

Comment: Btw, shell and common control changes from XP onwards are often quite badly documented (not sure if Microsoft fired all their documentation writers or if they just lost interest, but it's unfortunately how it is), so you often have to just try stuff and make informed guesses about how things work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you're setting the style - it's *when* you're setting it that's the problem.

You need to set the `TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES` extended style **before** you set `TVS_CHECKBOXES`. This is because setting `TVS_CHECKBOXES` triggers the creation of a state imagelist for the treeview, and this imagelist only includes the "partial" images if the partial style is set at the time it's created. The imagelist isn't recreated automatically if `TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES` is set later on.

Additionally, you can't specify `TVS_CHECKBOXES` in the call to `CreateWindowEx` if you want to use the partial checkboxes style, since there's no way to set `TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES` until the control has been created.